# Adding Zoom Controls to a normal XML layout

Tags: android, zooming

I just want to know, whether it is possible for me to add zoom controls to my XML layout. If yes, can anyone direct me to a sample based on it. Or any help based on it will help me much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a few controls (e.g. WebView and MapView) have built-in zoom. You will need to implement your own zoom logic to any other View and/or layout.

If you are just asking about the buttons to control the zoom, just add the following code to your layout:

```
<ZoomControls
    android:id="zoomControls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

(note that this code will add the buttons, but not any actual zoom functionality)

Check the api [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomControls.html). You will need to set up two listeners for those controls, on for zoom in and one for zoom out. Those are standard `OnClickListener`s like with any other button. You'll have to zoom in/out inside the `onClick(View v)` callback.

Comment: I don't even know what you want to zoom. Regardless, I added the listener details to the question.

Comment: i want to zoom a TableLayout how can i do that using ZoomControls